# jQuery selector startWith in the oposite way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an easy and elegant way to select all the elements with an attribute that match the beginning of a String.

In other words, the oposite of `$("myTag[name^="myString"])` where the `name` value shall start by `myString`, whilst I want `myString` to start by the `name` value.

So far I have

```
let path = window.location.pathname;
$('nav li a[href^="'+path+'"]').addClass("active");
```

Comment: What issue you are getting now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no native DOM methods to get elements by the substring of an attribute name (or jQuery that I'm aware of https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/), you can only match the full attribute name, e.g.:

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('[attr]');
console.log(elem);  // null

elem = document.querySelector('[attribute]');
console.log(elem); // <div attribute="value">Test</div>
```

```html
<div attribute="value">Test</div>
```

So you'll have to write something yourself, perhaps like this:

```js
// Optional startingNode and tagName to speed up the search
function getElementsByAttributeSubstring(substr, startingNode, tagName) {
  const matchedElements = [];

  substr = substr.toLowerCase();
  startingNode = startingNode || document.body;
  tagName = tagName || '*';

  const allElements = startingNode.querySelectorAll(tagName);

  for (const elem of allElements) {
    if (elem.hasAttributes()) {
       for (const att of elem.attributes) {
         if (att.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(substr) === 0) {
           matchedElements.push(elem);
           break;
         }
       }
    }
  }

  return matchedElements;
}

console.log(getElementsByAttributeSubstring('match'));
```

```html
<div matchThis="value">1
  <div matchThis="value">2</div>
  <div dontMatch="value">
    <div matchThis="value">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="para">
  <div matchThis="value">4</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a filter function that filters your jquery object using the `startsWith()` function.

If you want to make it a bit more elegant you could write a jQuery plugin that does the same.

```js
var path = "http://www.test.com";

$('a').filter((index, node) => {
  return $(node).attr('href').startsWith(path);
}).addClass("active");
```

```css
.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.test.com/abc">test1</a>
<a href="http://www.test2.com/efg">test2</a>
<a href="http://www.test2.com/ijk">test3</a>
<a href="http://www.test.com/mno">test4</a>
```